# Drag and Drop in API Level 10 in Android

Tags: android, api

I need to make an application where I can drag one View into another, retrieving data of the dragged view. (Similar as when one drags and drops an icon into the recycle bin).

I found the [this manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html), but unfortunately, it requieres API level 11, and my app must be for API level 10 (gingerbread).

How should I do what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I realized my answer wasn't really helpful at all. So I just deleted it. I'm not sure how to accomplish drag and drop without the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OnClickEvent or onTouchEvent to do it <10 API

I use the following code for a View:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    view.bringToFront();
     switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         Log.i(TAG,"Action Down");
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         Log.i(TAG,"Action Move");
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         Log.i(TAG,"Action Up");
         break;
     }
return true;    
}
```

Follow also [this example](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/) (there is a recycle bin also :) )
I hope it can help you.